How can a React form dynamically add and subtract inputs depending on users' previous inputs?
I am making a MERN app in which users can submit a form containing information that will be variable depending on their needs. I want the form to dynamically show inputs based off of an option they make earlier in the form. For example, if a user types '7' into the numPeriods input, seven new inputs should display on the page. Currently, my form looks similar to this:
<form onSubmit={createNewSchedule}>
     <input type="number" 
          placeholder={'Number of periods (2 - 10)'}
          min="2"
          max="10"
          value={numPeriods}
          onChange={ev => setNumPeriods(ev.target.value)} />
     <button style={{marginTop: '5px'}}>Create Schedule!</button>
</form>

I would like all of the user inputs to happen on one page, and be submitted in one form and one click. Is there a way to have the form dynamically add and subtract new inputs based purely on what is typed into numPeriods?
I also need to figure out how to ensure that no matter what value is input into numPeriods, the Mongoose schema will accept it and add it to my MongoDB database.
